# Filter combobox in a GridView filled with txt file

Tags: c#, winforms

Im having a problem when i try to filter my gridview trough combobox basicly when i click on the button "Procurar" the grid doesnt update but the row im in just switch. i will explain with the images

[image]

then when i choose a different Category "Categoria" it does this

[image]

Basicically it overwrote my original row with the new one that as the Categoria "Vegan".

here is the code:

```cs
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string receitas = @"receitas.txt";
    if (File.Exists(receitas)) {
        StreamReader sr2 = File.OpenText(receitas);
        string linha2 = "";
        int x = 0;
        while ((linha2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null) {
            string[] campos2 = linha2.Split(';');

            if (comboBoxCategorias.SelectedItem.ToString() == campos2[2]) {

                if ((txtTitulo.Text == "") || (txtIngredientes.Text == "")) {

                    dataGridReceitas[0, x].Value = campos2[0];
                    dataGridReceitas[1, x].Value = campos2[1];
                    dataGridReceitas[2, x].Value = campos2[2];
                    dataGridReceitas[3, x].Value = campos2[3];

                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
        sr2.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in the debugger. That should enable you to see what's happening.

Comment: Load all of your data in a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable). Set the DataTable as the `DataGridView.DataSource`. When you select a category from the ComboBox, use the [DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) to filter the Rows that match the criteria (so you also need to load the data once). Use a BindingSource if you need to update other controls when a selection changes.

Comment: its solved guys thanks anyways the solution was adding this line of code dataGridReceitas.Rows.Clear(); on the beggining of the button click =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridReceitas.Rows.Clear();
        string receitas = @"receitas.txt";
        if (File.Exists(receitas))
        {
            StreamReader sr2 = File.OpenText(receitas);
            string linha2 = "";
            int x = 0;
            while ((linha2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] campos2 = linha2.Split(';');

                if(comboBoxCategorias.SelectedItem.ToString() == campos2[2])
                {

                    if((txtTitulo.Text == "") || (txtIngredientes.Text == ""))
                    {
                        dataGridReceitas.Rows.Add(1);
                        dataGridReceitas[0, x].Value = campos2[0];
                        dataGridReceitas[1, x].Value = campos2[1];
                        dataGridReceitas[2, x].Value = campos2[2];
                        dataGridReceitas[3, x].Value = campos2[3];

                        x++;
                    }


                }



            }
            sr2.Close();
        }
    }
```

the solution was adding the code dataGridReceitas.Rows.Clear(); to clear the grid and just appearing the rows i wanted also adding the DataGridReceitas.Rows.Add(1) so when the search result is bigger than 1 the aplication dont crash